# Free memory occupied by cudaMemGetInfo

Tags: cuda, gpu

I have the following simple code to find available GPUs

```
int * getFreeGpuList(int *numFree) {
    int * gpuList;
    int nDevices;
    int i, j = 0, count = 0;

    cudaGetDeviceCount(&nDevices);
    gpuList = (int *) malloc(nDevices * sizeof(int));
    for (i = 0; i < nDevices; ++i) {
        cudaSetDevice(i);
        size_t freeMem;
        size_t totalMem;
        cudaMemGetInfo(&freeMem, &totalMem);
        if (freeMem > .9 * totalMem) {
            gpuList[j] = i;
            count++;
            j++;
        }
    }
    *numFree = count;
    return gpuList;
}
```

The problem is that `cudaMemGetInfo` occupies some memory (~150MB in my case) in each GPU. This code is a part of a bigger program that runs for a long time, and I often run several processes at the same time, so in the end the memory occupied by this function is significant. Could you please let me know how I can free the GPU memory occupied by `cudaMemGetInfo`? Thanks!

Comment: `cudaSetDevice` establishes a context, that is where the memory goes and there is nothing you can do about it

Comment: Hi @talonmies. I found this function `cudaDeviceReset`. I tried and it seems to serve my purpose. I put it at the end of the for loop (before setting the next device), but I am not sure if it may contain any lurking danger. Do you have any idea?

Comment: That will destroy the context. But if your intention is to use the context for something, then you will stop that something from working

Comment: @talonmies No the only thing I need after this is the list of free devices. From the documentation
> Explicitly destroys and cleans up all resources associated with the current
device in the current process.  Any subsequent API call to this device will
reinitialize the device.
This is exactly what I need. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Do you want to write a short answer with your solution. I will happily upvote it. Then we have an answer for the next person with the same question

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I posted an answer for this question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on some insight from [talonmies](https://stackoverflow.com/users/681865/talonmies) above that [`cudaSetDevice`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1g159587909ffa0791bbe4b40187a4c6bb) creates a context and occupies some memory in the device, I found out that [`cudaDeviceReset`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__DEVICE.html#group__CUDART__DEVICE_1gef69dd5c6d0206c2b8d099abac61f217) can "explicitly destroys and cleans up all resources associated with the current device in the current process" without affecting other processes on the same device.

Update Nov 26: If one wants to query GPU info, it's better using the [NVML](https://docs.nvidia.com/deploy/nvml-api/) library. In my experience, it is much faster and does not take up memory for simple memory and name queryings.

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer